# Derivatives of parametric curve

Tags: calculus

Given the curve $x = t^3 + 3t + 1 ,  y = t^2 + 4t - 4$

A. Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in terms of $t$.

B. Find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ in terms of t

I need help answering those please.
For A). the answer I got is $\frac{4}{3t}$ I'm not sure if it is correct.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Thanks! Just edited it!

Comment: I'm not sure how I managed to do that. That was a mistake. I fixed it. My bad!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Need to use chain rule and quotient rule to get these derivatives.

$x = t^3 + 3t + 1 , y = t^2 + 4t$

$\frac{dx}{dt}$ = $3t^2$+3

$\frac{dy}{dt}$ = 2t+4

$\frac{dt}{dx}$ =$\frac{1}{3t^2+3}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ =$\frac{dy}{dt}$$\frac{dt}{dx}$=$\frac{2t+4}{3t^2+3}$

$\frac{d^2y}{d^2x}$ =$\frac{d\frac{2t+4}{3t^2+3}}{dt}$ $\frac{dt}{dx}$
=$\frac{2(3t^2+3)-(2t+4)(6t)}{(3t^2+3)^3}$ =  $\frac{-2t^2-8t+2}{9(t^2+1)^3}$